# Преобразование JSON строки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получаю JSON строку по ссылке: `https://app.heroku.com/vac/2` (ссылка для примера)

Как мне распарсить JSON средствами javascript или jquery?

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для разбора JSON строки можно использовать [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
JSON.parse('true');            // true
JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null');            // null
```

---

При использовании функции [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) не нужно напрямую вызывать `JSON.parse`, так как она уже вызывается внутри.

Так как `jQuery.getJSON` всего лишь обертка над обычным запросом, то и результат можно получать так же. Например в *success* обработчике

```
$.getJSON( "url", function( data ) {
    //data - javascript объект, результат обработки полученного json с помощью JSON.parse
});
```

[**пример на plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CGZsFIM1Mm7GHBVtGj0f?p=preview)

Comment: Не получается получить поле title `var a = jQuery.getJSON('https://app.heroku.com/vac/2');      var b = JSON.parse(a);

alert( b.title );`

Comment: @Влад, естественно не получается, посмотрите справку по [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) и примеры как его использовать

Comment: Просьба привести пример, много чего попробовал, не получается.

Comment: @Влад, обновил ответ

Comment: @Влад, смотрите ошибки в консоли браузера

Comment: Спасибо, понял, буду разбираться!

Answer (score 1):

Парсит JSON.parse, но что бы избежать ошибок парсинга нужно его перехватывать или полетят ошибки.

```
(url) => { 
 let data;
  try {
    data = JSON.parse(url); // Парсим
  } catch(e) {
    data = null; // Перехватываем ошибку
  }

  if (data==null) return false; // Значит ошибка синтаксиса

  return data; // 100% валидный результат парсинга
}
```